# Is using Discord intents with discord.py "bugged" with pylint as I get a pylint error: "Assigning to attribute " " not defined in class slots"

Tags: python-3.x, discord, discord.py, python-3.8, pylint

I am currently working on a small discord bot using the newest versions of pylint, python3.92, and discord.py.
While using discord intents I encountered a pylint error that has me stumped.
This is a more general question as whatever I am doing is still working and doing what I intend it to do in my actual project.
However this error I can't seem to work around or get rid off is seriously bothering me as I used discord.py intents as per the documentation as far as I know.
This snippet is from a test bot to showcase the specific errors.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

intents = discord.Intents.default()

intents.members = True 
intents.presences = True

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='.', intents=intents)

@bot.command()
async def ping(ctx):
    ctx.send("pong")

bot.run('TOKEN')
```

Now pylint is showing me two errors in this code, both considering the intent attribute assignment.

[image]

From the docs:

```
 import discord
 intents = discord.Intents.default()
 intents.typing = False
 intents.presences = False

 # Somewhere else:
 # client = discord.Client(intents=intents)
 # or
 # from discord.ext import commands
 # bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents=intents)
```

One possibility I found is the following workaround:

```
intents = discord.Intents(members=True, presences=True)
```

However as I am planning to use different functions in one bot and don't want to have to add all intents I need manually I plan sticking to  `discord.Intents.default()` if possible.

These errors do not hinder the functionality or cause any other errors as far as I can tell. The error is the same with different types of intents, not just with privileged intents.
My questions would be:

1. Am I doing something wrong?
2. How can I get rid of these
   errors?

Unfortunately my knowledge of the language, discord.py and pylint is not advanced enough to change things around and get rid of the error in a proper way.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In theory, the wrong code would look like this ([source](https://vald-phoenix.github.io/pylint-errors/plerr/errors/classes/E0237.html)):

```
class Foo:
    __slots__ = ('bar',)

    def __init__(self, bar, baz):
        self.bar = bar
        self.baz = baz # [assigning-non-slot]
        self.setup()

    def setup(self):
        pass
```

And the correct code like this:

```
class Foo:
    __slots__ = ('bar', 'baz')

    def __init__(self, bar, baz):
        self.bar = bar
        self.baz = baz
        self.setup()

    def setup(self):
        pass
```

Now, if the code in this current form works for you, and especially if this is the official and easier way of using your dependencies... then it's a false positive from pylint and you can disable the message with `# pylint: disable=assigning-non-slot` or even for the whole project with the `pylintrc`